# Is it possible to read the inbox of the default Android e-mail client?

Tags: android, email

I read/search existing thread in this forum but according to someone that there is no way to access the inbox of default mail client of Android.

Until I found this one [send mail in android using the JavaMail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a)

and I can send email in my app but I want to do reading in my inbox. Could someone guide me about this?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default mail client of Android". There are many, depending on the device and the user.

There is no documented and supported API for working with the "inbox" of the Mail application from the open source project. Similarly, there is no documented and supported API for working with the inbox of the proprietary Gmail application.

Whether the email clients used by any specific device manufacturer have such APIs, I cannot say.

Comment: ohhh how sad.. even I searched on Google I haven't found any existing projects about this..